# rails query hstore where key IS NOT something or does not exist

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table with an hstore, and sometimes i'm using it store information for a checkbox. 
We use '1' for checked and '0' for unchecked. There is no default value for the hstore so a user can be in one of 4 states:

```
customer_a = Customer.new({properties: {checkbox: "1"}})   # checked
customer_b = Customer.new({properties: nil})               # unchecked(object doesn't exist)
customer_c = Customer.new({properties: {checkbox: "0"}})   # unchecked(unchecked)
customer_d = Customer.new({properties: {taco: "chicken"}}) # unchecked(key doesn't exist)
```

**Situation:** How can i find all 'unchecked' rows?

```
Customer.where(" customer.properties -> 'checkbox' NOT LIKE '1' ")
```

^^^does not work^^^ ignores customers with empty 'checkbox' key and where properties is empty

```
Customer.where("customers.properties -> 'checkbox' LIKE '%0%' OR customers.properties IS NULL")
```

^^^does not work^^^ also ignores where the key is missing

*Is there a better way to do this in a single query?*

**query should return `[customer_b, customer_c, customer_d]`**

current solutions:
- checked: `Customer.where(" customer.properties -> 'checkbox' LIKE '1' ")` 
- unchecked: `Customer.all - Customer.where(" customer.properties -> 'checkbox' LIKE '1' ")`

**is there a sql query returning rows where an hstore key doesn't exist?**

Comment: What about `@customers.where("customers.properties -> 'checkbox' LIKE ? OR customers.properties IS NULL","0")` (not sure about the syntax here)

Comment: @MrYoshiji thank you! that gets me part of the way there. I think i need to look for empty strings as well but i'm not quite sure yet

Comment: I think it might be easiest for me to subtract all users with the checkbox from the total amount of customers

Comment: What about the opposite? `@customers.where("customers.properties -> 'checkbox' NOT LIKE ?", 0)`

Comment: @MrYoshiji the opposite only returns results where the key `checkbox` has a written value. it does not return items where the key is missing or where the entire properties object is missing

Comment: Hmm I see... Then you might be right, maybe you have to find everybody who has `1` as a property value for `checkbox`, then select all the Customer that are not in this query. Something like: `Customer.where('id NOT IN (?)', Customer.where({properties: {checkbox: "1"}}).pluck(:id).presence || -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to find all records where hstore is empty, use

```
Customer.where(properties: ['',nil])
```

OR

```
Customer.where("properties='' OR properties IS NULL")
```

EDIT

Assuming you want to find everything without 1 from your comments about empty string can you try this,

```
Customer.where("properties -> 'checkbox' NOT LIKE '1' OR NOT(properties ? 'checkbox') OR properties = '' OR properties is null")
```

To check for hstore contains a key

```
properties ? 'checkbox'
```

checks for contains and I am doing a not on it to find ones without checkbox and then empty properties. Let me know whether it works.

Comment: thanks for answering, but question is about a specific hstore key, not the entire hstore. For example if i commonly put `{name: "tom"}` then i would like to query where name is nil or does not exist.

Comment: any answers for the above comment?

Answer (score 0):

This will return all records where the checkbox key is either null or not "1" aka checked

```
customer = customer.where("properties->'checkbox' != ? OR properties->'checkbox' IS NULL", "1")
```